# Office 365 - Distribution groups On premises to Cloud

Tags: office365, exchange-server, azure-active-directory

I am performing the migration in a hybrid environment: Office365 / Exchange. Our users are synchronized using AD Connect and the email boxes have already been migrated from on premises to the cloud. The intention is to later disable the exchange on premises server.

My question is regarding distribution groups. If I uninstall the exchange server, does migration of the distribution groups to the cloud necessary?
Because these groups are created in Active Directory and synchronized with my tenant. If I uninstall Exchange, will those groups be removed too?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> does migration of the distribution groups to the cloud necessary?

Usually, it's necessary.But Azure AD Connect doesn't sync all groups from your on-premise. However, you can [Filter synced users via AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-configure-filtering).

> If I uninstall Exchange, will those groups be removed too?

NO, those groups still exists.You can see more details about  managing or removing objects that were created through directory synchronization from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) in [this Support article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-configure-filtering).

Comment: Configuring Office and Exchange is not programming. Do not answer off-topic questions.